# How to extract key and value from using preg_match_all?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a php file containing language variables that look like this:

```
define('YES', 'Yes');
define('NO', 'No');
define('HOME', 'home');
define('UNKNOWN', 'Unknown');
define('YEARS', 'years');
define('DAYS', 'days');
define('LOADING', ' Long text ...
...end of text');
```

I need to parse it, extract keys and values for further usage. 
What would be a REGEX pattern for this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?PHP
$STR = "define('YES', 'Yes');
define('NO', 'No');
define('HOME', 'home');
define('UNKNOWN', 'Unknown');
define('YEARS', 'years');
define('DAYS', 'days');
define('LOADING', ' Long text ...
...end of text');";

if( $i = preg_match_all( "/define\(\s*'([^']+)'\,\s*'([^']+)'\);/si" , $STR , $m ) )
{
    print_r( $m );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get all the defined constants look at this function [**get_defined_constants**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php)